# Need help converting this IntelliJ run configuration to a command line one

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've got this working run configuration in IntelliJ which I want to convert tro a command line one. Been trying few things but it can't seem to locate my class file.

[image]

Can someone suggest the correct command to run please?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you found the way to convert?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to run this configuration from within IDEA, open the "Run" tool window and copy the command from there.

Note that IDEA adds some specific settings and you'll have to remove them, like removing idea_rt.jar from classpath, etc.